# C# Convert Int64 to String using a cast

Tags: c#, string, casting, int, long-integer

How do you convert an integer to a string? It works the other way around but not this way.

```
string message
Int64 message2;
message2 = (Int64)message[0];
```

If the message is "hello", the output is 104 as a number;

If I do

```
string message3 = (string)message2;
```

I get an error saying that you cant convert a long to a string. Why is this. The method .ToString() does not work because it converts just the number to a string so it will still show as "104". Same with Convert.ToString(). How do I make it say "hello" again from 104? In C++ it allows you to cast such methods but not in C#

Answer (score 3):

`message[0]` gives first letter from string as `char`, so you're casting `char` to `long`, not `string` to `long`.

Try casting it back to `char` again and then concatenate all chars to get entire string.

Answer (score 2):

`ToString()` is working exactly correctly.  Your error is in the conversion to integer.

How exactly do you expect to store a string composed of non-numeric digits in a long?  You might be interested in `BitConverter`, if you want to treat numbers as byte arrays.

If you want to convert a numeric ASCII code to a string, try

```
((char)value).ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative approach is using `ASCII.GetBytes` method as below

```
string msg1 ="hello";
byte[] ba = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg1);
//ba[0] = 104 
//ba[1] = 101 
//ba[2] = 108 
//ba[3] = 108 
//ba[4] = 111 

string msg2 =System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ba);
//msg2 = "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
string message3 = char.ConvertFromUtf32(message2);
```

- **104 is the value of "h" not "hello".**

Answer (score 1):

There is no integer representation of a string, only of a char. Therefore, as stated by others, 104 is not the value of "hello" (a string) but of 'h' (a char) (see the [ASCII chart here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters)).

I can't entirely think of why you'd want to convert a string to an int-array and then back into a string, but the way to do it would be to run through the string and get the int-value of each character and then reconvert the int-values into char-values and concatenate each of them. So something like

```
string str = "hello"
List<int> N = new List<int>();
//this creates the list of int-values
for(int i=0;i<str.Count;i++)
  N.Add((int)str[i]);
//and this joins it all back into a string
string newString = "";
for(int i=0;i<str.Count;i++)
  newString += (char)N[i];
```